# how to write active record of rails for this query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Could anyone help me to write active record for this query..

```
SELECT c.name,c.profile_pic,cq.title FROM `coaches` as c join course_queries as cq on
    c.id = cq.coach_id WHERE cq.coach_id=1
```

`class CourseQuery < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :coach
end`

`class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_queries
end`

Comment: please put you model structure an association here

Comment: @Vishal please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way

```
Coach.joins(:course_queries).select("coaches.name,coaches.profile_pic,course_queries.title").where(:course_queries => {:coach_id => 1})
```

You can used eger loading with outer join as

```
@coaches = Coach.includes(:course_queries).where(:course_queries => {:coach_id => 1})
```

An select you data by

```
 @coaches.each do |coach|
    puts coach.name
    puts coach.course_queries.first.title   
   end
```

You can get all course queries by

```
  @coaches.each do |coach|
    puts coach.name
    coach.course_queries.each do |course_query|
       puts course_query.title 
     end
   end
```

Comment: why using first.title here?

Comment: when iam using this looping ,iam getiting only first result

Comment: yes beacuse i m selected only forst result of course queries if you want all the course queiries then again loop throuh it as editiing